# Why does `postmap` generate such a huge database?

Tags: postfix, mac-osx

I have a one-line `/etc/postfix/generic` to configure address mapping for smtp relay through my email provider. Running `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/generic` generates a 29,360,128 byte Berkeley DB file from this 52 byte text file. That seems a little excessive!

Similarly, a 65 byte `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` file balloons to 37,748,736 bytes in DB form.

This is on an APFS partition on macOS High Sierra. A similar file on an HFS+ partition on Sierra produces a much more reasonable 16384 byte file, which makes me wonder whether it's a block size thing and APFS is,... causing something odd to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're correct on the file system issues.

I'm running postfix relay on centos 6, all of my berkley DB files are the same size regardless of their originating file

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20497 Oct 14 23:00 access
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12288 Oct 14 23:00 access.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1802 Oct 11 23:21 recipient_access
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12288 Oct 11 23:21 recipient_access.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2140 Jan 17 14:31 sender_access
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12288 Jan 17 14:31 sender_access.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12609 Oct 21 15:09 transport
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12288 Oct 21 15:09 transport.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12494 Mar 27  2007 virtual
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12288 Dec  8  2016 virtual.db
```